# fairseq-interactive: error: unrecognized arguments: --path

Tags: python, bash, spell-checking, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm trying to run the Transformer Spell Checker [`xfspell`](https://github.com/mhagiwara/xfspell).

- I created a virtual environment: `python3 -m venv .pyenv`
- installed the requirements: `pip install -r requirements.txt`
- downloaded the pretrained model and extracted its content: `tar zxvf model7m.tar.gz`
- ran the following command:

```
$ echo "tisimptant too spll chck ths dcment." \
    | python src/tokenize.py \
    | fairseq-interactive model7m/ \
    --path model7m/checkpoint_best.pt \
    --source-lang fr --target-lang en --beam 10 \
    | python src/format_fairseq_output.py
```

However, I get the error:

```
fairseq-interactive: error: unrecognized arguments:  --path model7m/checkpoint_best.pt  --source-lang fr
```

I don't see the `--path` argument in the `fairseq-interactive` [documentation](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line_tools.html#fairseq-interactive), so I don't know why it was used in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the fairseq-interactive documentation (generation section).

[image: screenshot of fairseq doc]